# insert into a local table from a distant table in Oracle

Tags: java, sql, database, plsql, oracle11g

i would like to insert into a local table (in a local database), all the rows from a distant table. here's what i'm looking for :

```
insert into LocalTable (Column1,Column2,...,ColumnN) values (select * from DistantTable);
```

does anybody knows how could i do this (if there is a way)??

i'm aweare that there is a way using a java program, by copying the DistantTable rows in a file, then extracting those rows using a StringTokenizer then putting them to LocalTable. but it would be really good if i can perform this using only SQL queries.

Comment: distant table means , its located in separate db?

Comment: @loki yes, located in another DB in a server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a [database link](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28310/ds_concepts002.htm) in the local database, pointing at the remote database, and then type:

```
INSERT INTO LocalTable SELECT * FROM RemoteTable@DBLink;
```